# Is there a function to get log and pct change?

Tags: return, percentage, finance, logarithm

I would like to compare log and pct change f the two symbols, but the following error appears:

KeyError: 'Adj Close'

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import yfinance as yf
start = datetime.datetime(2017, 10, 1)
end = datetime.datetime.now()
symbols = ['BTC-USD', 'ETH-USD']
df = pd.DataFrame()

for i in symbols:
 data = yf.download(i, start=None, end=None,show_errors=("True"),
                period="4y", interval="1mo")
df[i] = data['Adj Close'].pct_change().dropna()


df['log_stuff'] = \
np.log(df['Adj Close'].astype('float64')/df['Adj Close'].astype('float64').shift(1))
df[['pct_change', 'log_stuff','df']].plot();
```

Comment: Can you please add tags `python` and `finance`, to make sure your question can be found? With regards to uour question, just inspect `data.columns` and make sure the spelling of your column name matches the column name in the data.

Comment: Thanks. But I can not get what you mean by data.columns . please I need to rewrite the code.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following. Please note, that you can also pass a list to `download()`, so no loops are required.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import yfinance as yf

symbols = ['BTC-USD', 'ETH-USD']
data = yf.download(symbols, period="4y", interval="1mo")

# calculate pct return
pct_data = data['Adj Close'].pct_change()
pct_data = pct_data.add_suffix('_pct')

# calculate log returns
log_data = np.log(data['Adj Close']) - np.log(data['Adj Close'].shift(1))
log_data = log_data.add_suffix('_log')

# combine returns and drop na values
combined_data = pd.concat([pct_data,log_data], axis=1).dropna()

print(combined_data)
```

This will yield the following output:

```
            BTC-USD_pct  ETH-USD_pct  BTC-USD_log  ETH-USD_log
Date
2017-12-01     0.383326     0.692483     0.324490     0.526197
2018-01-01    -0.277987     0.477813    -0.325713     0.390564
2018-02-01     0.017298    -0.235276     0.017150    -0.268240
...
```